# How to select fields from populated documents but by using select on parent document?

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to implement a Spotify API-like field limiting

i.e. `items(a,b(c,d))` will select items.a, items.b.c, items.b.d

In my case, I have a populated field (added_by) inside my main document (tracks.items)

```js
"tracks": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/5e8a3a6e263b6431749b1c2f/tracks",
    "items": [
      {
        "is_local": false,
        "_id": "5e8a3d7214fc7751301abd87",
        "added_at": "2020-04-05T20:20:02.773Z",
        "added_by": {
          "type": "artist",
          "_id": "5e8a399a263b6431749b1c27",
          "name": "Artist Account",
          "uri": "spotify:user:5e8a399a263b6431749b1c27",
          "id": "5e8a399a263b6431749b1c27"
        }
     ]
}
```

I want to select fields inside the populated field (added_by) by sending a limit query `tracks.items.added_by(type,name)`
but without having to parse the string manually to call mongoose's select object on population as it is really hard to parse the string for many populated fields

What I mean is, in my code I have this

```js
Playlist.findById(playlistId, queryObject)
    .populate([
      {
        path: 'tracks.items.track',
        select: populationFields,
        populate: [
          {
            path: 'album',
            select:
              'album_type artists id images name type uri external_urls href',
            populate: {
              path: 'artists',
              select: 'external_urls href id name type uri'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'artists',
            select: 'external_urls href id name type uri'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tracks.items.added_by',
        select: 'name id type uri href'
      }
    ]),
  queryParams
)
```

I want to implement the field limiting query shown above on this easily